# How to download streaming flash videos?

Tags: firefox, video, flash

I am acquainted with Firefox extensions like VideoDownloadHeper, DownThemAll etc. and also other command line tools like youtube-dl  for downloading flash videos from popular sites like Youtude,Metacafe etc. But these are not working in the present case.

I want to download streaming flash videos from sites like [NEJM](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1414123#t=articleTop). Greasemonkey with the unembed script is not working either. Could you please help me download this small [video](http://www.nejm.org/action/showMediaPlayer?doi=10.1056%2FNEJMoa1414123&aid=NEJMoa1414123_attach_1&area=) from the above site?

Thanks in advance!

Moksha

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Firefox (this works for mp4 Videos)

Note: First disable your flash plugin in the plugin settings.

Then do this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>
2. Play the video
3. You will see below in the debug window a file being pulled. If it is an mp4 file then just copy the link address and do `wget`.

   For example:

   ```
    wget http://89.40.181.19/ivuqjoscyu2qedz7nljb7fjfaainuqpqufkh5xk6kkheqzdny3rzc2uhnkka/v.mp4 -O outputfile.mp4
   ```

Then your download will begin.

Answer (score 0):

For NEJM, you can right-click the video and choose **Save link as** (Firefox has to save it). If it doesn't work, you can use `wget` in terminal.

For this video, the URL is [this](http://www.nejm.org/doi/video_original/10.1056/NEJMoa1414123/NEJMoa1414123_v01.mp4).

With `wget` there are two ways of downloading.

The first will keep the video file name and copy it to the current directory while rhe second will change it. `/path/to/file` is the path to the renamed video.

```
wget [video url]
wget [video url] -o /path/to/file
```

If the video has special characters you can try like this (or the same but using `-o`):

```
wget 'http://www.nejm.org/doi/video_original/10.1056/NEJMoa1414123/NEJMoa1414123_v01.mp4'
```

Comment: Right click doesn't give download option. wget doesn't work either.Please check the link  for yourself if you can download.

Comment: Thank you! Please let me know how did you get this? In my case, right click doesn't give any option. wget is showing HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2015-03-16 09:48:52 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error. Please let me know the specific wget command.

Comment: I don't know really. Just right clicked the video frame. You can try looking the page source for the mp4 file. For the error 500 - try waiting some time and do it again.